# Creating new columns based on existing column storing a string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Given a table with users' data and their purchase history, stored as a string - I'd like to create using SQL new columns (column per product) that we'll indicate whether the customer purchased this product.
Current table:

| user_number | products |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | (4,2,8,10,20) |
| 13 | (9,3,8,15) |
| 52 | (8,14) |
| 4 | (10) |

Desired table:

| user_number | 2 | 3 | 4 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 14 | 15 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 13 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 52 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
execute immediate (
select ''' select * from (
  select user_number, product
  from your_table, unnest(split(trim(products, '()'))) product
) pivot (count(*) for '_' || product in (''' || string_agg('"' || col || '"', ',' order by cast(product as int64)) || '''))
''' from (
  select distinct '_' || product as col, product, 
  from your_table, unnest(split(trim(products, '()'))) product  
))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: have you tried?